# How catch event clicking by radio button?

Tags: angularjs

Now I have HTML elements:

```
<input type="radio" ng-change="saveSubscriber(1)" name="type" value="1">
<input type="radio" ng-change="saveSubscriber(2)" name="type" value="2">
```

And Angular JS event in controller:

```
$scope.saveSubscriber = function (type) {
   // Do Ajax here
}
```

This sample does not work for me, may be replace on `ng-click()?`
My example, that does not work too:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="type" ng-click="saveSubscriber();" name="type" value="2">

$scope.saveSubscriber = function () {
   console.log($scope.type);
}
```

Comment: I think problem is in that inputs are created dynamically by JS?

Comment: Guys, I resolved this task, thanks for help

Comment: plz post ur answer so other can vote u and learn from you. Thank u

Comment: Okay, later will post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign some `ng-model` to fire `ng-change` event, `ng-model` of both radio button should be same like i used `test`, that will change `ng-model` value on click of it & will fire `ng-change` event

**Markup**

```
<input type="radio" ng-change="saveSubscriber(test)" name="type" 
ng-value="1" ng-model="test"/>
<input type="radio" ng-change="saveSubscriber(test)" name="type" 
ng-value="2" ng-model="test"/>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.saveSubscriber = function(type) {
  console.log(type);
};
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/o1kGhlI2iSHlduGLDHEd?p=preview) Here

Comment: Really same `ng-model="test"`? What is give me? If I send value in function `saveSubscriber()`

Comment: It is not good solution, bacause event works at once after load page

Comment: @Sahe why you do think its not a good solution? Check my updated answer and plunkr

Answer (score 0):

You can use this codes for watch your radio buttons.

```js
    
    $scope.$watch('value', function(value) {
           console.log(value);
//Do your things!
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="value" ng-value="1">
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="value" ng-value="2">
```

Comment: I have some radio buttons with different values